Shade smooth artifact
I've got a strange smooth shading artifact. I don't see any triangles or messed up topology (that I can tell).

I've tried adding more geometry and making sure the edges are even. Does anybody know how to fix this?


if my answer doesn't help, please provide a photo with annotation (a circle) where the problem occurs. thx.

As Chris says it's not clear what artefact you're talking about

I hope it's more visible now. There's a ring that goes around the front of the mesh. It may be the way that the light's hitting it now that I look at it closer though.

Isn't it just a curvature of the mesh? You can add a smooth modifier if you want to smooth it up...

your face orientation is wrong:

if you repair that, maybe that helps.

that does help, but it still didn't resolve the issue.
